# Ampscript compress https link with bilty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I try to compress a link with ampscript, I use this code :

```
%%[
var @Token, @Link, @BitlyUrl, @urloffre, @ref

SET @Token = "xxxxxxxx"

/* Do not update below this line */

SET @ref=AttributeValue('ref')

SET@Link =Concat("https://........", @ref)

SET @BitlyUrl = Concat("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=",@Token,"&longUrl=")

SET @toHttpGet = Concat(@BitlyUrl,@Link,"&format=txt")

SET @urloffre=TreatAsContent(HTTPGet(@toHttpGet))

]%%

%%=v(@urloffre)=%%
```

But it's doesnt work, do you have suggestion ?

Comment: I believe you have to parse the httpget response. I would first do something like `set @response = httpGet(@toHttpGet)` and then print out your response with `%%=v(@response)=%%` or `Output(@response)` inside the ampscriptblock

Comment: Thanks for your response.

SET @BitlyUrl = Concat('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=',@Token,'&longUrl=')
set @response=httpGet(@toHttpGet)
]%%
%%=v(@response)=%%                                                                               but its doesnt work

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteShaman Try [URL encoding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/urlencode.htm) the link being passed first: `SET @Link = URLEncode(Concat("https://........",@ref),1,1)`

Comment: I would also point out bit.ly rate limits these calls unless you have an enterprise license